# How do I implement a default route for users not logged in with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Using Node.js and Express, I want to have users who are not logged in always redirected to the main page. What is the simplest way of achieving this? Ideally I'd not have to add code to every route checking whether someone's logged in.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define 'not logged in', but say that status is stored in `req.session`. In that case, you could add a middleware that will redirect not-logged-in users to a login page:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path === '/loginpage') // pass requests for login page
    next();
  else
  if (! req.session || req.session.isLoggedIn !== true) // check logged in status
    res.redirect('/loginpage'); // redirect to login page when not logged in
  else
    next(); // else just pass the request along
});

app.get('/loginpage', function(req, res) {
  res.send('login page');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I work on node a long time ago but it should works

```
function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    next(); // allow the next route to run
  } else {
    // require the user to log in
    res.redirect("/"); // or render a form, etc.
  }
}

// Automatically apply the `requireLogin` middleware to all
// routes starting with `/`
app.all("/*", requireLogin, function(req, res, next) {
  next(); // if the middleware allowed us to get here,
      // just move on to the next route handler
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a redirect loop when the user is requesting the login page?

Comment: @robertklep I've just discovered that yes, it does.

Comment: @tsvallender you could still use `requireLogin` separately for each route you want protected, though, like with Akshat's answer :)

Comment: @robertklep That's exactly what I needed thanks, if you want to add that solution as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Or if you want to edit yours, ant.

Comment: @tsvallender it's ant's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can user something like [passport](http://passportjs.org/).It makes checking the authorized routes a lot simpler

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
 if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
 res.redirect('/login')  //Or whatever your main page is 
};
```

You can now check your routes like this

```
app.get('/account',ensureAuthenticated,routes.account);
```